# DJANGO saving model types in a field as Generic Foreign Keys

Tags: python, django

I want to create a new model that look something like this:

```
class Note(models.Model):
   id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   title = ...
   message = 
   entity = *****************
```

I want the ******* - to be a foreingKey for any model -  not object but model. I don't want entity to be multiple objects of the same model - just the model.

So if the note comes from a Post entity should save as Post, if it comes from a Notification the foriengKey should be to Notification.

Is there a way to do this in django or is my only option to just save the entity name as a String value? and filter for the Model name like.

```
# Get all the notes for POST Model
Note.objects.filter(entity="Post")
```

Comment: guess what, django has a GenericForeignKey https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations

Comment: I have been checking those out - don't they save objects and not the actual model type. I just wanna save the model like `Post` not `Post post1` and `Post post2`. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: but what good is that? It's not an SQL relationship.

Comment: I want to be able to do something like

`
  Note.objects.filter(entity="Post")
`
to return all the notes from ALL the Post models not just the one instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it sounds like what you are really looking for is '[choices](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#choices)'.

> An iterable (e.g., a list or tuple) consisting itself of iterables of
>   exactly two items (e.g. [(A, B), (A, B) ...]) to use as choices for
>   this field. If this is given, the default form widget will be a select
>   box with these choices instead of the standard text field.

now your model becomes

```
class Note(models.Model):
    POST = "Post"
    COMMENT = "Comment"
    ...
    ENTITY_CHOICES( (POST,POST), (Comment, Comment) ...)

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = ...
    message = ...
    entity = models.CharField(max_lenth=5, choices=ENTITY_CHOICES)
```

Now you can run the query in your comment

```
 Note.objects.filter(entity="Post")
```

Comment: Thanks this works well. Thanks! I'll try and maybe get a list of choices automatically from Django - as a list of all the models so it's less typing.

Thanks

Comment: glad to have been of help

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`contenttypes`](https://kite.com/python/docs/django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType) app in Django.

```
class Note(models.Model):
   id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
   entity = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

You will be able to assign `entity` model instances, and also perform queries on them (`filter(entity=MyModel.objects.get(id=1))`

Comment: This looks fine but is there a way to make entity equal to a model and not an instance of a model? So just the actual model type not a specific instance of that model.

Comment: I don't think so since `object_id` field cannot be null. Actually `content_type` is the id of model (yes there is a special table for that that keeps track of all models) and object_id is the value of primary key in model's table.
The entity is a kind of virtual field that doesn't exist in our Note model's table. It is derived from `content_type` and `object_id` fields